# Python3 module import confusion

Tags: python, import, module, pip, local

When I install a python module (for example `mediafile`) with pip I can import it like this:

```
from mediafile import MediaFile
```

and it works perfectly.

But then I install it to a different location (`pip install --target="C:/msys64/home/myname/myprogram/tools/mediafile/" mediafile`), I can only import it like this:

```
from tools import mediafile
```

and importing `MediaFile` just doesn't work. (I tried `from tools.mediafile import MediaFile` and a couple of other variations with no success).

Here's an ouptut :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MediaFile' from 'tools.mediafile' (unknown location)
```

When I try to use `mediafile.MediaFile` it gives me this error :

```
AttributeError: module 'tools.mediafile' has no attribute 'MediaFile'
```

Any idea where I got the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `pip install --target=/path/to/package mypackage` will install the package **inside** the directory you have specified, i.e. at `/path/to/package/mypackage`. In your case it is probably at `C:/msys64/home/myname/myprogram/tools/mediafile/mediafile`.

If this is the case you should be able to import it with:

```
from tools.mediafile.mediafile import MediaFile
```

but don't do this - instead you should delete it and reinstall with

```
pip install --target="C:/msys64/home/myname/myprogram/tools/" mediafile
```

Then you should be able to import it with

```
from tools.mediafile import Mediafile
```

---

The problem with the above approach, as you have discovered, is that packages will expect to be able to import their own dependencies just using `import dependency` - they will not know about your `tools` directory. To fix this, and to make your own imports easier, you will need to add the directory to your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) for how to do this in Windows.

Alternatively you can add it inside the script itself:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("tools")
from mediafile import MediaFile
```

However setting PYTHONPATH is the preferred way to do this.

Note that I have assumed you deleted and reinstalled `mediafile` as above, so your directory structure should be:

```
tools
├── mediafile.py
├── mutagen
├── ...
```

Comment: I tried this one first, and I can indeed import `MediaFile`. The problem is, it has a dependency, `mutagen` which isn't recognized now (`ModuleNotFoundError`)